# В реактовском приложении получаю верные данные(comment) только после второго клика, подскажите где ошибка

Tags: reactjs, map, render

при клике на просмотр поста открывается модалка с полной ифой о посте и комментарри к нему, но данные о коментах приходят правильно только после повторного просмотра(открытия модалки).
вот основной код...

```
const Posts = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts.posts);
    const post = useSelector(state => state.post.post);
    const comments = useSelector(state => state.comments.comments);
    const [commentsForPost, setCommentsForPost] = useState([])
    const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchPosts());
      dispatch(fetchComments());
    }, [dispatch]);

    const getComments = postId => {
      dispatch(fetchCommentsForPost(postId));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      setCommentsForPost(comments);
    }, [comments])
    
    const getPost = postId => {
      dispatch(fetchPost(postId));
    };
    
    const someFunc = (event) => {
      getComments(event);
      getPost(event);
      setShowInfo(true);
    };

    const cancelShowInfo = () => {
      setShowInfo(false);
    };

    const formSubmitHandler = async comment => {
      await dispatch(createComment(comment));
      setShowInfo(false);
    };

    return (
      <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
        <Grid
            item
            container
            direction="row"
            spacing={2}
        >
          {posts.map(post => {
            return <PostCard
                key={post._id}
                id={post._id}
                title={post.title}
                timeOfCreater={post.timeOfCreater}
                image={post.image}
                user={post.user.username}
                getPost={() => someFunc(post._id)}
            /> 
          })}
          <Modal
            isShown={showInfo}
            closeModal={cancelShowInfo}
        >
            <div className="modal-card">
              <PostCard
                title={post.title}
                timeOfCreater={post.timeOfCreater}
                description={post.description}
                image={post.image}
                user={post.user}
              /> 
              <div className="comment-block">
                  <Typography variant="h5">
                    Comments:
                  </Typography>
                  {commentsForPost.map(comment => {
                    return <CommentCard
                      key={v4()}
                      id={comment._id}
                      author={comment.user}
                      comment={comment.commentText}
                    />  
                  })}
              </div>
              <div className="modal-addcomment">
                  <Typography variant="h5">
                    Add comment
                  </Typography>
                  <CommentForm
                    keys={post._id}
                    id={post._id}
                    onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}
                  /> 
              </div>                    
            </div>
        </Modal>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  };
  
  export default Posts;
```

это commentActions

```
import axios from '../../axios-forum';
import {
  CREATE_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_COMMENTS_FOR_POST_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS,
} from '../actionTypes';

const fetchCommentsForPostSuccess = (comments) => {
    return {type: FETCH_COMMENTS_FOR_POST_SUCCESS, comments: comments}
};

export const fetchCommentsForPost = (postId) => {
    const id = postId;
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/comments?post=${id}`);
            dispatch(fetchCommentsForPostSuccess(response.data));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};

const fetchCommentsSuccess = (comments) => {
    return {type: FETCH_COMMENTS_SUCCESS, comments}
};

export const fetchComments = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('/comments');
            dispatch(fetchCommentsSuccess(response.data));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};

const createCommentSuccess = () => {
    return {type: CREATE_COMMENT_SUCCESS}
};

export const createComment = comment => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            await axios.post('/comments', comment);
            dispatch(createCommentSuccess());
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: После клика на что? Укажите сразу все детали, зачем заставляете искать самому :)

Comment: вижу только один onClick, но не вижу функции `fetchComments`

Comment: @entithat - извините, мой первый вопрос здесь :)

Comment: это, конечно, хорошо, но функцию fetchComments я не нашел все-таки (

Comment: @entithat fetchComments находится в actions и вызывается в useEffect, но меня больше беспокоит fetchCommentsForPost(), именно она отвечает за вызов комментариев к определенному посту, они как раз и отстают на один клик

Comment: проблема заключается в рендере, рендер comment происходит раньше чем меняется state comments